# ERRO = Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input

Tags: php, php-domdocument

Bom dia, estou com o seguinte erro:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string supplied as input.

Este erro ocorre no meu servidor grátis, o estranho é que localmente tudo funciona normal.

Alguém sabe o porquê?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <link  href="css/estilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <script type="" src=""></script>
   <script type="" src=""></script>
   <link rel="" type="" href="">
   <body>

   <h2></h2>

   <?php

   $url = "https://www.agrolink.com.br/cotacoes/graos/";


   $chll = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
   curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
   curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_POST,false);
   //curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
   curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
   curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($chll, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    $err = curl_error($chll);
    $mensagem = curl_exec($chll); 
     curl_close ($chll);

     //echo $mensagem;


     libxml_use_internal_errors(true) and libxml_clear_errors();
      $html = new DOMDocument();
      $html->loadHTML($mensagem);





        $arra =  array();
       foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('td') as $span){ 

       $x0 = $span->nodeValue.'</br>';
       echo $x0.'</br>'.'</br>';


       };

       ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o curl está desabilitado nesse servidor gratuito e o método `$html->loadHTML($mensagem);` está recebendo null

Comment: Era isso mesmo.